# Rails NoMethodError in Classified#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I'm following along with a book called Rails Solutions: Rails Made Easy, its written for rails 2 but I'm using rails 3 which is making things very interesting and making me learn a lot which is good, but I'm stuck with the above problem. I've read around on Stack and other websites I think it could be a routes issue but the book so far hasn't mentioned anything about routes.

routes.rb

```
List::Application.routes.draw do
  match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
end
```

app/views/classified/show.html.erb

```
  <p>
    <strong>Title: </strong> <%= @classified.title %><br />
  </p>
```

app/controllers/classified_controller.rb

```
class ClassifiedController < ApplicationController
  def list
    @classifieds = Classified.find(:all)
  end
  def show
     @classifieds = Classified.find(params[:id])
  end
   def new
@classified = Classified.new
  end
  def create
    @classified = Classified.new(params[:classified])
    if @classified.save
      redirect_to :action => 'list'
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
  def edit

  end
  def update

  end
  def delete

  end
end
```

NoMethodError in Classified#show

Showing /home/mark/Documents/RoR/list/app/views/classified/show.html.erb where line #3 raised:

undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #3):

1: 
2:

3:     **Title:**  <%= @classified.title %>
4:

Comment: You'll get this error a lot. `undefined method 'title' for nil:NilClass` means the object on which you're calling `title` is nil. Here, it's `@classified`, see why in Tomdarkness' answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller you used `@classifieds` but in your view you use `@classified`. Change one to match the other.

Comment: Thank you, very strange whilst looking at his controller he mixes classified and classifieds for each of the methods, a bit confusing and I'm not sure why but thank you anyway.